# Unable to deploy JAX-WS service on Glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, glassfish, jax-ws

I have created a simple dynamic web project in eclipse.
The web service implementation is as follows:
[image]

Web.xml:
[image: Web.xml]

Project structure:
[image]

When I generate the war and deploy it on glassfish, it deploys fine. But, it does not recognize it as a web service and does not generate any wsdl/endpoints. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 5 and Java 8.

Comment: Have you looked at Glassfish's logs? Can you post them? How did you determine that it's not recognizing your web service? What was that error message?

Comment: Can you please let us know how you have generated war file? Is it via eclipse export war option? What target runtime environment you have choosed?